# Does a mini PCIe SSD fit into a Acer Aspire One?

Tags: ssd, compatibility, acer-aspire-one

Question: What, if any, mini PCIe SSDs fit into the mini PCIe slot of the Acer Aspire one AOD250?

---

Info: I have an Aspire One and I've been considering loading it with an SSD. The mini PCIe drives fascinate me and so I want to try that approach. Also they tend to be cheaper and not much slower. (at least not on Read time which matters more for a netbook) But I've heard that some times computers don't support certain mini PCIe cards. And I was wondering if anyone knew about the Aspire One? I tried asking Acer tech support, but they didn't know jack and spent the whole time informing that I would have to support my Ubuntu install on my own, which I was.

Anyway. Rant Aside, I'm looking at this drive:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820183252

It states it is exclusively for the Eee PC. now does that mean It was designed for the Eee PC but will work in my netbook. or is something going to go wrong? (like right now my concern is it physically not fitting.)

Any information would be appreciated. o7

Answer (score 1):

There's only one mini pci-e slot in the aspire, i have a d255. It's taken up by the wi-fi card, so unless you want to use a usb wi-fi adapter then it would work.

Comment: Ah that is where you are wrong sir. As I have an empty slot and I still have wireless. Ergo, there are two. However, one is half size, the other is full size. the half size one is where you find you're wireless card. the full size is, for me, empty.